# How to put the condition for the minimum triangle side to this perimeter and getting the answer about the minimum one

Tags: java

As you see this program supposed to give me number of lines. 
I want to know how to put a condition give me the minimum triangle side 
like if I give the number 5 to the (line) it will loop five times and each line
I have to put 3 separated numbers but I can't find a way to put a condition to give me which one of them is the minimum one.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangles {
private int side[];

public static void main(String args[]) {
    double  line;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of Triangles:");
    line = s.nextInt();

    int side[] = new int[(int) line];

    System.out.println("Please, insert lengths of the sides of this triangles(3 real numbers per line) ");

    for (int i = 0; i < side.length; i++) {// for reading array
        side[0] = (int) s.nextDouble();
        side[1] = (int) s.nextDouble();
        side[2] = (int) s.nextDouble();
                    double perimeter = side[0]+side[1]+side[2];
                    System.out.println(perimeter);
                    System.out.println("Enter the next  Triangles:");
    }
    line--;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your requirement i have modified it.
i hope this will solve your problem, please let me know if you need any help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double  line;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Triangles:");
        line = s.nextInt();

        int side[] = new int[3];//because every triangle has 3 sides
         double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;//assuming perimeter of a tringle will be grater than zero
        while(line-->0){//we need to loop as many no Triangles
            System.out.println("Please, insert lengths of the sides of this triangles(3 real numbers per line) ");
       // for (int i = 0; i < side.length; i++) {// for reading array
            side[0] = (int) s.nextDouble();
            side[1] = (int) s.nextDouble();
            side[2] = (int) s.nextDouble();
                        double perimeter = side[0]+side[1]+side[2];
                        if(perimeter<min){
                           min = perimeter;
                        }
                        System.out.println(perimeter);
                        //System.out.println("Enter the next  Triangles:");
        //}
        }
        System.out.println("Minimum Perimeter :"+min);
       // line--;

    }
```

Comment: but if i need 3 lines like                                                                                     2 3 6 = 11                                                                                                               5 6 8 =  19                                                                                                             6 7 4 = 17                                                                                                             here is my problem  i want this one of condition to till me that the minimum is the first line

Comment: i am not able to understand your requirement , why you are giving 4 numbers 11 5 6 8 a triangle should have 3 sides how come you are giving 4th side ?

Comment: no i mean the first line of input is 2 then 3 then 6 -- the second line of input is 5 then 6 then 8 and the third line of input is 6 then 7 then 4   at the end i want the sum of the first line and the sum of the second line and the sum of the third line  here is my question how to put a condition tilling me which one the the minimum line

Comment: i have updated my answer , still if you want those sides along with min perimeter take 3 temp variables and assign those with corresponding sides inside the if block